# ArrayList and HashMap confusion

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, filesize

```
public class PackageTabActivity extends ListActivity{
HashMap<String,Object> hm ;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> applistwithicon ;
  private static final String APP_NAME = "app_name";
  private static final String APP_ICON = "app_icon";
  private static final String APP_SIZE = "app_size";

  Method getPackageSizeInfo = null;
  PackageManager pm  ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    pm = getPackageManager();

    applistwithicon = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

    try {
        getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    new AppDetails().execute();
}

private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
            : false;
}


class AppDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String , Object>>>
{
     private  long app_apk_size;
     ProgressDialog mDialog;
     @Override
     public void onPreExecute()
     {
             mDialog = new ProgressDialog(PackageTabActivity.this);
             mDialog.setCancelable(true);
             mDialog.setMessage("Loading... " );
             mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
             mDialog.setProgress(0);
             mDialog.show();
     }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> doInBackground(
            Void... params) {

           ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> app = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();  

        List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0); 

        long []  size = new long[packs.size()];


        for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {

            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);



            if(!isSystemPackage(p))
            {
                   /*  String package_name = p.applicationInfo.packageName;
                     appname[i] = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                     icon[i] = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
                     size[i] = GetSize(package_name);
                 //  Log.v("Test", "app_name = " +appname[i]+"  app_size = "+size[i]);*/


             app= GetSize(p);


           }


        }


             //  


        return app;
    }
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> GetSize(final PackageInfo pInfo)
{
try
{
    getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm,  pInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub()
    {
        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException
        {
            app_apk_size= pStats.codeSize/1024;
            if(app_apk_size!=0)
            {
                // If I uncomment-out the below commented-out lines, I get
                // an incorrect result:

                // hm = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
                // hm.put(APP_SIZE, app_apk_size);
                // hm.put(APP_NAME, pInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
                Log.v("apksize", "appsize = "+app_apk_size+"appname = "+pInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
                // applistwithicon.add(hm);
            }
        }
    });
}
catch(IllegalAccessException e) {}
catch(IllegalArgumentException r) {}
catch(InvocationTargetException w){}
return applistwithicon;
}
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> result)
    {
        mDialog.dismiss();
         CustomAdapterList myAdapter = new CustomAdapterList(result,PackageTabActivity.this );

         setListAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
}
```

}

But if I uncomment-out the commented-out lines, the wrong result gets logged.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What does this have to do with an ArrayList or HashMap?

Comment: And what do you expect vs. what happens?

Comment: What do you expect? What happens? We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `pInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)` does, but try to put the result in a var instead of calling method twice.